# How to refer C structure member in mails

Tags: c, structure, member

This is not strictly programing question.

I have been coding in C++ in past. During mail conversation I was able to address class member I by doing `foo::bar`. But now I am coding in pure C and mailing with people that does not necessarily know C++. I am wondering if `foo::bar` is clear that I am addressing to field `bar` in `struct foo`.

If there is another convention that I can use I would like to know it but I am unable to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no syntax for that (which is sometimes a shame).

You're going to have to use "`bar` in `struct foo`" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In `c`, the `.` and `->` are known as *structure reference* and  *structure dereference*  [member of] operator.  in your case, you can use like

```
struct foo fooVar;
fooVar.bar
```

or

```
struct foo * fooVar;
fooVar->bar            //assume `fooVar` is allocated memory.
```

to mean that you're addressing to field `bar` in a variable `fooVar` of type `struct foo` / `struct foo *`.

If you don't want to use any *notation/ operator*, I'm afraid you've to type the whole phrase like *variable `bar` of the `struct foo` structure*.